# How to fetch certain keyword's record in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I would like to LIKE search.

If 'product' column has "AQ" string display data.

I wrote below code but I couldn't get any record.
Could you teach me right code please?

```
    public function w_mo_fb_m()
{    
    $word = "AQ";
    $images = ImageGallery::where('product', 'like', "%$word%")->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('w_mo_fb_m',compact('images'));        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about try this.

```php
where('product', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%')

//or

where('product', 'LIKE', "%{$word}%")
```

If this still not working you may need to run raw SQL to see if you can get any record. (you need to replace `ImageGallery` with your actual table name)

```php
DB::select('select * from ImageGallery where product LIKE = ?', ['%'.$word.'%']);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  where('product', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%') code Worked! Thank you so much!